# Cross Domain AJAX in IE9 not working in CQ5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, aem

I need to send a cross domain request using jQuery AJAX. But it is not working in IE9.

**The strange thing is, it works fine when I try it in a standalone HTML file. But breaks when done in a CQ page.**

The js code is below:

```
 $.support.cors = true;

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "https://www.some.external.web.service",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: "{"key":"value"}",
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) { alert("success"); },

         error: function (xhr, status, error) { alert("AJAX Error:status: "+ status+ "\nerror: " + error + "\nxhr.status: " + xhr.status + "\nResponseText: \n" + xhr.responseText);  }
        });
```

I have tried using datatype as 'jsonp' but still no avail. In IE9, it never returns the 'Success' handler and always goes to the 'error' handler.

The error shown is 'Transport Error'.

The webservice is in https and my page can be either http(author) or http(publish)

I already have the `$.support.cors = true;` set before the ajax. What am I missing ?

Comment: What is the error? Are you going from https to http?

Comment: `data: "{key:"+value+"}"` ? (Just first seen)

Comment: updated the question. JSON data is not a problem. the error is 'Transport Error' and the service is https while my page can be either http or https

Comment: To perform CORS requests in IE8/9 (IE7 doesn't support CORS) you must use the XDomainRequest object. jQuery does not implement this for you, you'll have to either send the request manually or include a jQuery plugin that implements it. in IE10+, this shouldn't be an issue, however there are other subtle differences that could still cause problems.

Comment: Also note, `$.support.cors = true;` is pointless, `crossDomain: true,` does nothing in your case, and `processData: false,` isn't needed if `data` is indeed a json string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't use JSONP or XDR because of the GET and text content respectively.

For this, I added an iframe in my page whose HTML resides in the client's server. So we post our data to the iframe and the iframe then posts it to the webservice. Hence the cross-domain referencing is eliminated.

We've added a 2-way origin check to confirm only authorized page posts data to and from the iframe.

```
<iframe style="display:none;" id='receiver' name="receiver" src="https://iframe-address-at-client-server">
 </iframe>

//send data to iframe
var hiddenFrame = document.getElementById('receiver').contentWindow;
hiddenFrame.postMessage(JSON.stringify(message), 'https://client-server-url');

//The iframe receives the data using the code:
window.onload = function () {
    var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
    var eventer = window[eventMethod];
    var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
    eventer(messageEvent, function (e) {
        var origin = e.origin;
        //if origin not in pre-defined list, break and return
        var messageFromParent = JSON.parse(e.data);
        var json = messageFromParent.data;

        //send json to web service using AJAX- same origin now  
        //return the response back to source
        e.source.postMessage(JSON.stringify(aJAXResponse), e.origin);
    }, false);
}
```